# python django restful api - can't always catch a specific post request

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am using python Django restful api framework. I am trying to catch all the userPreference post requests in views.py. I don't know why I can't catch all the post request with my code. Here is my views.py

```
class aUserViewSet(aAPIViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
    '''
    This function limits the queryset to User's data
    '''
    queryset = super(aUserViewSet, self).get_queryset()

    qs1 = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
    if qs1.exists():
        if "userpreference" in qs1.model._meta.db_table:
            tp = self.ws_userPreference(qs1, self.request.user.username)
        else :
            print("no handle needed")
    else :
        print("qs1 not exist")
    return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)       

def ws_userPreference(self, qs1, username):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        print("get userPreference post")
    else :
        print("get userPreference non post request")
return 0


class UserPreferenceViewSet(aUserViewSet):

    queryset = UserPreference.objects.all()
    print "In userPreference viewset"
    serializer_class = UserPreferenceSerializer
    filter_fields =  ('activationResponse','startTimeForDecisionChoice', 'endTimeForDecisionChoice', 'valueScale1', 'valueScale2', 'valueScale3', 'valueScale4',  'decisionPreference',  'waypointsCompleted', 'numberOfSessionsToDecisionChoice','created', )
    filter_backends = (URLFilter, )
    ordering_fields = ('activationResponse','startTimeForDecisionChoice', 'endTimeForDecisionChoice', 'valueScale1', 'valueScale2', 'valueScale3', 'valueScale4',  'decisionPreference',  'waypointsCompleted', 'numberOfSessionsToDecisionChoice','created',  )
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's the question exactly ?

Comment: I try to catch all the post request from userPreference api and I missed some post call. I don't know why..

Comment: @CK8 Please try to indent your code a little better.

Comment: I just format my code a little better.